# 3 Nested for loop in macro

Tags: vba, for-loop, nested

[image]I'm trying to list out all the plans in column A, and all the areas for each plan in column B. So it would be plan 1 with area 1 and 2, plan 2 with area 1 and 2, etc. My codes currently list out plan 1, plan 2, etc in column A, but it only lists out area 1 and 2 for plan 1, and it stops there. How do you make it to keep going and list out Area 1 and 2 for the rest of the plans? Thank you :))

So Column A would have plan 1, plan 2, etc in order. And, column B would be area 1, area 2, area 1, area 2, etc

```
  'List out all areas for all plans

For Plan = 0 To 5

    'List out all areas within a plan

For Area = 0 To 6

    'List out one Area

    For Row = 2 To 10
        Sheets("S").Cells(Area * 51 + Row, 2) = Sheets("S").Cells(Area + 2, 31)
        Next Row
Next Area
Next Plan
```

(The one on the left in picture is what I have now, and I'm trying to get to the picture on the right. Thanks :))

Comment: Show your data. A picture would be enough.

Comment: Hi Masoud, how do you add a picture? Thanks :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Comment: I think I might be able to use YowE3K's code to get to what I need. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the number of loops you have, it sounds like you would be better off just using a counter for your output row.

```
Dim FirstPlan As Long:  FirstPlan = 0
Dim LastPlan As Long:   LastPlan = 5
Dim Plan As Long

Dim FirstArea As Long:  FirstArea = 0
Dim LastArea As Long:   LastArea = 6
Dim Area As Long

Dim FirstRow As Long:   FirstRow = 2
Dim LastRow As Long:    LastRow = 10
Dim myRow As Long    ' Avoid "Row" as a variable name
Dim OutputRow As Long

OutputRow = 2 'Specify first row to be written to

'List out all areas for all plans
For Plan = FirstPlan To LastPlan

    'List out all areas within a plan
    For Area = FirstArea To LastArea

        'List out one Area
        For myRow = FirstRow To LastRow                
            'I'm guessing at this line
            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "A").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(Plan - FirstPlan + 2, "AD").Value

            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "B").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(Area - FirstArea + 2, "AE").Value

            'I'm guessing at this line
            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "C").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(myRow - FirstRow + 2, "AF").Value

            'Set up ready for the next row to be written
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Next
    Next
Next
```

---

Alternatively `OutputRow` could be calculated every time it is needed:

```
Dim FirstPlan As Long:  FirstPlan = 0
Dim LastPlan As Long:   LastPlan = 5
Dim Plan As Long

Dim FirstArea As Long:  FirstArea = 0
Dim LastArea As Long:   LastArea = 6
Dim Area As Long

Dim FirstRow As Long:   FirstRow = 2
Dim LastRow As Long:    LastRow = 10
Dim myRow As Long    ' Avoid "Row" as a variable name
Dim OutputRow As Long

'List out all areas for all plans
For Plan = FirstPlan To LastPlan

    'List out all areas within a plan
    For Area = FirstArea To LastArea

        'List out one Area
        For myRow = FirstRow To LastRow                
            OutputRow = ((Plan - FirstPlan) * (LastArea - FirstArea + 1) + _
                         (Area - FirstArea)) * (LastRow - FirstRow + 1) + _
                         (myRow - FirstRow) + 2

            'I'm guessing at this line
            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "A").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(Plan - FirstPlan + 2, "AD").Value

            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "B").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(Area - FirstArea + 2, "AE").Value

            'I'm guessing at this line
            Sheets("S").Cells(OutputRow, "C").Value = _
                   Sheets("S").Cells(myRow - FirstRow + 2, "AF").Value

        Next
    Next
Next
```

---

If you are not used to the control flow of loops, try running the following example in an empty worksheet:

```
Dim colA As Long, colB As Long, colC As Long
Dim r As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For colA = 11 To 12
        For colB = 21 To 23
            For colC = 31 To 34
                r = r + 1
                .Cells(r, "A").Value = colA
                .Cells(r, "B").Value = colB
                .Cells(r, "C").Value = colC
            Next colC
'The following statement will be executed AFTER processing colC as 34
        Next colB
'The following statement will be executed AFTER processing colB as 23
    Next colA
'The following statement will be executed AFTER processing colA as 12
End With
```

Comment: This is really helpful !! When there're 3 loops, does it finish the most inner loop and start the first loop all over again? Or does it move to the second loop? Thank you ! :)

Comment: @JBB - each time a `Next` statement is reached, the counter for that loop is incremented and then control returns to first statement within the loop (if you haven't exceeded the end value) or to the following statement (if you have).  So after the innermost loop ends in the example above, control moves to the `Next` of the middle loop and its counter is incremented and the innermost loop will possibly be executed again.  Once the innermost loop ends for the last time in the middle loop, the outermost loop's counter is incremented, and the middle loop starts again, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @JBB I just added a very simple example to the end of the answer - try running it (or even better, stepping through it line-by-line using F8) and it may help you understand loops better.

Comment: oh nice! Thank you :)